# static vs local definition of a pointer

Tags: c

For one of my projects, I am using a pointer to point a float type global variable. I am wondering if I define this as static vs local pointer with in a function, would one be a better definition than the other.

For Ex:

```
float a; 
float b;
void foo(void)
{
  static float *ptra;
  float *ptrb;   

  ptra = &a;
  ptrb = &b;
}
```

Comment: What do you need this pointer for?

Answer (score 2):

A `static` pointer is used to implement a function which returns the `same buffer` to the program, allocating it the first time it is called

Answer (score 1):

Apart from

```
ptrb = &b;
```

being pointless (scope etc...)

Why use static pointer?

It serves no purpose and is very bad coding style.

Comment: Why is this bad coding style? The example was obviously for learning purposes and there are of course cases when statics are very handy.  Since you are limiting the scope they offer some kind of encapsulation (actually it is the "same" than a global which is just needed sometimes).

Comment: Bad habits are hard to get rid of. Static variables in windows/unix are treated differently. Multi-threaded programming is also a problem

Comment: It can be a problem. And that is also why you only use them in rare cases. I did not know that the behaviour is different in terms of platforms. But yes using them in multi threaded situations is almost in every case a bad idea. Since your program is then not "thread safe".

Answer (score 1):

If using a non `static` definition covers all needs, then use this. If it doesn't, use `static`.

Answer (score 0):

`static` is persistent so if you declare it in a function, when you call the function again the value is the same as it was last time.

So use them when you need same value whenever function is called.

And about local pointer if pointer points to a local variable in the function block , so outside function block scope of variable ends and the pointer  becomes dangling pointer . And thus accessing such pointer will cause segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

I think the other answer is correct. I would add this as explanation: A static pointer (or variable) has the same life cycle than a global pointer (or variable), except that its "scope" is limited to the function.
It is not only used to return the same buffer (only one use case). You can also use it for other situations. For example if you want to implement a global counter or just save some state during the whole program life cycle (can be useful for a recursive function).

From my personal experience you may use it only in very rare cases.